# i was wondering if i i can change the bubblesort algorithm on geeksforgeeks a bit and attain the same result

Tags: python, bubble-sort

So the code on geeks for geeks for bubble sort is this:

```
# Python program for implementation of Bubble Sort


def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    # Traverse through all array elements
    for i in range(n):

        # Last i elements are already in place
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):

            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
            # Swap if the element found is greater
            # than the next element
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]


# Driver code to test above
if __name__ == "__main__":
arr = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8]

bubbleSort(arr)

print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print("%d" % arr[i], end=" ")
```

I was wondering in the for loop; for i in range(n) if you could reduce the algorithm by one step by changing it to for i in range(n-1).

I was thinking that because even for worst case scenario, don't you only need a maximum of len(array)-1 steps for it to be fully sorted or am I overlooking something here?

This was just kind of a random question I had in mind

Comment: As a side note, your test case already has the last element in its correctly sorted position. That probably isn't a good test to use when checking whether the last step is necessary.

Comment: Yes you could use `range(n-1)` but It would not make a meaningful difference given that, as it is now, when `i` reaches `n-1`, the `for j` loop will not perform any iteration anyway because its range will be from zero to `n-(n-1)-1` which is `range(0,0)`.  What would make an actual difference is to break the `for i` loop when the  `for j` loop makes no swaps.

Answer (score 0):

You are, to use an old phrase, putting lipstick on a pig.  There is absolutely no reason to use bubble sort, not in Python and not in any other language.  It is a simple algorithm, but it is incredibly slow, and changing the range by 1 isn't going to affect that.

There are many better sorting algorithms.  One of the best goes by the name `sort` in Python.

But the answer to your question is yes.